# Why are multiple prices being saved per product?

Tags: python, csv, xpath, web-scraping, mechanize

I've been trying to work out myself why this code is generating multiple prices per product when the data is saved in the csv.  It seems that all prices for the row on the page that a product is on are saved under each of the products in that row.  Obviously what I'm trying to do is just save one price per product, not 3 or 4 each.

I haven't been able to figure this out myself.  What needs to be changed so that only the correct price for each product is stored?

```
import mechanize
from lxml import html
import csv
import io
from time import sleep

def save_products (products, writer):

    for product in products:

        writer.writerow([ product["title"][0].encode('utf-8') ])
        for price in product['prices']:
            writer.writerow([ price["value"][0].encode('utf-8') ])

f_out = open('ssdResult.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(f_out)

links = ["http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals", "http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=2", "http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=3","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=4","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=5","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=6","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=7","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=8","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=9","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=10","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=11","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=12","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=13","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=14","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=15","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=16","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=17","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=18","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=19","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=20","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=21","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=22","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=23","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/research-chemicals?p=24","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/cannabinoids","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/cannabinoids?p=2","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/cannabinoids?p=3","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/cannabinoids?p=4","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/cannabinoids?p=5","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/cannabinoids?p=6","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/cannabinoids?p=7","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/pellets","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/pellets?p=2","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/pellets?p=3","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/herbal-blends","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/herbal-blends?p=2","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/branded-products","http://sciencesuppliesdirect.com/branded-products?p=2"]

br = mechanize.Browser() 

for link in links:

    print(link)
    r = br.open(link)

    content = r.read()

    products = []        
    tree = html.fromstring(content)        
    product_nodes = tree.xpath('//div[@class="category-products"]/ul')

    for product_node in product_nodes:

        product = {}
        try:
            product['title'] = product_node.xpath('.//li/div[2]/h2/a/text()')

        except:
            product['title'] = ""

        price_nodes = product_node.xpath('.//li/div[2]/div[1]/span')

        product['prices'] = []
        for price_node in price_nodes:

            price = {}
            try:
                price['value'] = price_node.xpath('.//span/text()')

            except:
                price['value'] = ""


            product['prices'].append(price)
        products.append(product)
    save_products(products, writer)

f_out.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean? Please include the input (html?) , what output you are getting. and what you expected.

Comment: The input are the links in the code.  If you run this you'll see the results in the csv have multiple prices for each item, whereas on the page there is one prices per item.

Comment: It looks like you are storing multiple prices

Comment: Yes that's right.  I'm trying to figure out why I'm storing multiple prices instead of just the corresponding price for each item.

Comment: is there no-one that has some advice for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Take a hard look at the data structure that you are creating. Frankly, it's a mess.
A quick look and as far as I can see, it's something like this:

```
[
{
'prices': [{'value': [u'\xa35.00']}, {'value': [u'\xa35.00']}, {'value': [u'\xa36.00']}
],
'title': ['500mg Nitracaine', '5 x 4mg Flubromazepam Pellets', '1 Bk-2C-B Pellet', '10 0.5mg Pyrazolam Pellets']
}
]
```

A List, containing a Set of prices and titles where the prices are stored as a List containing Sets of Lists, and the titles are a list.
I think!!!
My head hurts just looking at it. The result is that your CSV writing routine doesn't have a hope, the way that this data is structured. You are going to have to sort that out to have any hope of creating what you want.
The other thing is that even if you alter the code to store everything in usable structures, your code is not allowing for `old price` and `special-price` because `product_node.xpath('.//li/div[2]/div[1]/span')` is no longer the correct method of getting to the price that you want, instead it returns a sub-set, depending on where the first `old-price` is situated, so the number of prices does not match the number of products.